# Finding unique tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I want to find unique tuples based upon the following situation:

This is my data:

```
data  = [
    (1L, u'ASN', u'Mon', u'15:15:00'), 
    (2L, u'ASN', u'Tue', u'15:15:00'), 
    (3L, u'ASN', u'Wed', u'15:15:00'), 
    (5L, u'ASN', u'Fri', u'15:15:00'), 
    (7L, u'ASN', u'Sun', u'15:15:00'), 
    (15L, u'ASN', 'Reminder', '2014-05-26 15:29'), 
    (16L, u'ASN', u'Mon', u'15:15:00'), 
    (17L, u'ASN', u'Tue', u'15:15:00'), 
    (18L, u'ASN', u'Wed', u'15:15:00'), 
    (19L, u'ASN', u'Fri', u'15:15:00')
]
```

I want to find unique tuples ignoring the first element in the list, i.e

```
(1L, u'ASN', u'Mon', u'15:15:00'), 
(2L, u'ASN', u'Mon', u'15:15:00')
```

are the same.

How can I do it?

Comment: What should happen to duplicates? Keep the first? Keep the last? Keep all 0th-element values? Discard all of them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put them in a dict, keyed by the parts you want to be unique.

```
uniq = {d[1:]:d for d in data}
uniq = uniq.values()
```

The above will return the last of any data items that are non-unique. If you want the first instead, you can reverse the initial list.

If you only need to use a part of the data after finding the unique items, you can easily replace `:d` by e.g. `:d[0]` in the dict comprehension.

Comment: `for d in data: uniq.setdefault(d[1:], []).append(d)` will store all items as values for keys